# Getting an explicit formula from a recursive one.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a recursive formula of a sequence and I would like to find an explicit version, if possible. Here it is:

$$a_k = a_{k-1} \cdot k - k + 2$$
$$a_2 := 6$$

Is there any general approach I can take? Anything I tried hasn't worked yet (though I haven't been working on it for that long, so if you can just push me in the right direction that's great too). If I knew the formula, I could prove it by induction, but I don't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean to say "explicit" not "implicit".

Comment: Of course, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Divide both sides by $k!$ and let $$b_k=\frac{a_k}{k!}.$$

Comment: Oh wow, that was absolutely fantastic, thanks! So $a_k \leq k!e +1$ is always true. That was really fun. How'd you get the idea to divide by k! ? Don't think I could've thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

$a_k = ka_{k-1} - k + 2 = k((k-1)a_{k-2} - (k -1) + 2) -k + 2 = ... = k!a_{0} +2 - k + k(2 - (k-1)) + ... + k!(2 - (k-k))$
It may be possible to simplify the sum.